# Gazebo UI crashing on launch

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am new to the ROS community.  why is gazebo GUI crashing when you try simulation tutorial instruction 'roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch' ?

The error that I get is

[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 32382, exit code -6].
log files: /home/username/.ros/log/ef5ae1c0-9d25-11e0-99ad-001d0900b3d5/gazebo-2*.log

Any idea ?
bdw ..I am using ubuntu 10.04

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10364/gazebo-ui-crashing-on-launch/) by [adesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/737/adesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2011-06-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/737/adesh/) on 2011-06-23**:
Hi Dornhege, it has created just blank (o bytes) log files. So I am not sure why is it not logging anything.  One more thing that I observed it after I restart my machine, it works as a get around and I do not see a crash.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-22**:
Did you look in the logfiles? What do they say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please check per Bemfica's suggestion on graphics support first.
And list graphics card and driver are you using in this post.

You might want to try disabling Compiz to see if it helps.

Just double checking, but did you install diamondback version? if so, instead of roslaunching empty_world.launch, try

```
roslaunch gazebo_worlds debug.launch
```

upon gazebo crash, you should see gdb terminal in the console, type "bt"

```
(gdb) bt
```

and please post any outputs here.

thanks!

John

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/737/adesh/) on 2011-06-27**:
Thanks John.. using 'roslaunch gazebo_worlds debug.launch' seems to have solved this in diamondback.  Thanks again